# value notation for ENUMERATED alternative of a CHOICE

Tags: asn.1

With following specification

```
G-011 DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= 
BEGIN 
Payment-method ::= CHOICE {
  check        NumericString(SIZE (15)),
  credit-card  Credit-card,
  cash         NULL
}

Credit-card ::= SEQUENCE {
  type         Card-type,
  number       NumericString(SIZE (20)),
  expiry-date  NumericString(SIZE (6))-- MMYYYY -- 
}

Card-type ::= ENUMERATED {
  cb(0), visa(1), eurocard(2), diners(3), american-express(4)
}

END
```

I thought the value notation for a payment with cb would be:

```
value Payment-method ::= credit-card : cb
```

However, http://asn1-playground.oss.com/ fails to parse this value

What is wrong with my value ?

EDIT:
My bad, I did not read the spec carefully enough (thanks @Ilya)

```
value Payment-method ::= credit-card : { 
    type cb, 
    number "01234567890123456789", 
    expiry-date "042018"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing the `credit-card.type` field in the value notation? Because `cb` belongs to `type` field which belongs to `credit-card` one.

On a more general note, ENUMERATED type is just a bunch of named integers, while CHOICE is a finite collection of types that can be used for values.

Answer (score 1):

```
value Payment-method ::= credit-card : 
{
    type cb,
    number "00000000000000000000",
    expiry-date "012099"
}
```

I got that by switching the module to IMPLICIT tags and just writing the hex down I wanted it to interpret:

```
3080
  0A0100
  12143030303030303030303030303030303030303030
  1206303132303939
  0000
```